# 1004 error when trying to set name on xls worksheet

Tags: vba, xlsx

I'm trying to create worksheets with name taken from `sheet1` cells, but I'm always getting a `1004 error` when executing  `Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).name = companyName`

I tried setting the sheets name by `PrefferedName` and worked... and I also checked with a `MsgBox` that `companyName` variable has the last sheet's name...

```
Sub Find2()
    Dim i, k As Integer
    Dim j, l As Integer
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim dateAnnounced As Date
    Dim fromDate As Date
    Dim currentCellDate As Date
    Dim daysBefore As Integer
    Dim kk As Integer
    Dim from1 As Integer
    Dim companyName As Variant

    Set originsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    daysBefore = 30

    i = 3
    j = 4
    Counter = 0
    k = 5
    l = 4179
    dateAnnounced = Cells(i, j).Value

    For Each cel In Range(Cells(1, k), Cells(1, 4179))
        currentCellDate = cel.Value

        If currentCellDate = dateAnnounced Then
             MsgBox k
            Exit For
        End If

        k = k + 1
    Next cel

    kk = k
    from1 = k - daysBefore

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    companyName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j - 1).Value
    Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).name = companyName

    MsgBox name

    For Each cel In Range(Cells(1, from1), Cells(1, kk))
        If from1 = kk Then
             MsgBox cel.Value
            Exit For
        Else
            Counter = Counter + 1
        End If

        from1 = from1 - 1
    Next cel

    MsgBox Counter

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem, but one thing you should do is put Option Explicit at the top of this module. This forces you to declare all variables before using them. You will then see that "name" is not declared as a variable, which will affect one of your MsgBox statements. Also, though it doesn't affect your code here, note that `Dim i, k As Integer` means `Dim i As Variant, k As Integer`

Comment: Can you give us the value of companyname? Not longer than 31 characters, no " [ ] ? * \ / " in it?

Comment: Associated Group Inc is the companyName, No strange characters in it..

Comment: Although I may have a company name with other characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run this code more than once, you will get the 1004 run-time error because it will try to add a sheet with the same name.  All sheets must have a unique name.  You might need to add a check to ensure that a worksheet with the name does not already exist before creating a new sheet.  Something like:

```
companyName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j - 1).Value
WorksheetExists = False
For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If UCase(Sht.Name) = UCase(companyName) Then
        WorksheetExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next Sht
If WorksheetExists Then Exit Sub

ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = companyName
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a worksheet name that is not unique, you can also get error 1004 if the worksheet name is more than 31 characters long.
Try doing:
`Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).name = Left(companyName, 31)`